# Azure Kusto language query through all tables

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer, kql

I am trying to build a KUSTO query to verify that logs are coming to Azure log analytic tables or not. This is my code. This command work perfectly & give number of records it received. But Issue is it does not consider in the query output the table names that received zero(not any) logs

```
union withsource=sourceTable kind=outer Table1, Table2, Table3
| summarize AggregatedValue=count() by bin(TimeGenerated, 5m), sourceTable
```

Expected output:

```
| Table Name | Count |
----------------------
| Table1     | 5     |
| Table2     | 3     |
| Table3     | 0     | //If the count is zero, query output does not show the table name
----------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the values in the column for `bin(TimeGenerated, 5m)` in your expected output. I assume you didn't really want this column there (otherwise, I'm not sure what exactly you wish to see in the expected output for Table3, which has 0 records).

To get the output you want, use the following trick:

```
let DefaultResult = datatable(['Table Name']: string, Count: long) [
    "Table1", 0,
    "Table2", 0,
    "Table3", 0
];
union withsource=sourceTable kind=outer Table1, Table2, Table3
| summarize AggregatedValue=count() by bin(TimeGenerated, 5m), sourceTable
| union DefaultResult
| summarize Count = sum(Count) by ['Table Name']
| order by ['Table Name'] asc
```

Comment: Hi @Slavik N, Thank you for your support, yes I want to see in the output all tables and received log count, even-though that particular table does not receive any logs, it should be shown as 0.
Further, In Microsoft document, I found we can show values with Group Expression, but still no luck
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/summarizeoperator

Comment: Hi @UtpMahesh. If the input to `summarize` doesn't have a certain group-by key, then `summarize` won't output it (and I can't see where the doc says it does). That's why I've done a `union` with `DefaultResult`, where I put all the table names with `Count` = 0. Have you tried it? Does it output the result you expect?

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
let reCount = union withsource=sourceTable kind=outer  AppServiceFileAuditLogs,AzureDiagnostics, BaiClusterEvent
| summarize AggregatedValue=count() by sourceTable;
let tableList = datatable (name:string)
[
    'AppServiceFileAuditLogs',
    'AzureDiagnostics',
    'BaiClusterEvent'
];
tableList
| join kind=leftouter reCount on $left.name == $right.sourceTable
|project name,count = iff(isnull(AggregatedValue)==true,0,AggregatedValue )
```

Idea here is to do a left join with table expression having table names (tableList) and then place 0 where AggregatedValue is NULL.